# load modal dynamically in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have around 200 .txt files that needs to be shown with a popup modal.
I have a table with a button in each row. after clicking a button I want to pass the path of the file to the modal.

my problem is that the modal only loads the first row's .txt file.

```
 <?php
$path = "";
$path = storage_path($vm->name  . '.txt');
if (file_exists($path)) {
    ?>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <h3>
                            <?php
                            echo $path; ?>
                        </h3>

                        <?php
                        echo nl2br(file_get_contents($path)); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function alerts(x) {
            alert(x);
            fetch(x);
        }
    </script>

    <a href=# type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick="alerts('<?php echo $path  ?>')"> audit </button>
        <!-- <a href=# type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> audit </button> -->

        <? php
```

how do I make the modal so that it loads onclick instead of at initial page load

Comment: You have to make content of the model dynamic. On each click your model content should be changed. You can use ajax or something like that

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are many guides and examples of how to do this,  for example [here's the first result](https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-dynamic-content-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/) when searching for the keywords in your question title.